Show shortcode output in menu
I would like to show shortcode output in menu like below.

How can I do that ?

Please add below line in your functions.php file
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'do_shortcode');

This line will execute do_shortcode to your menu items and if there is any it will execute the shortcode.
